# NCBI E-utility to Find Shortest Citation Path Between Two Publications

Tags: literature

I'm trying to perform a thorough review of Hi-C and RNAi developments and have found myself looking at publication A (2011) and publication B (2015). B doesn't cite A explicitly but I'm sure there are papers linking the two and I'd like to find them. Are there existing utilities to help with this? I've used [NCBI E-utilities](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/home/api.shtml) in the past but would prefer not to rewrite an application that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pursue [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/). Example usage, similar to what I'm looking for, is given [here](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.fr/2010/02/path-from-egonwillighagen-to-jandot.html). (per a tip from the blog's author in response to my [cross-posting](https://www.biostars.org/p/163058/) on biostars)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the full citation graph is locked away in proprietary databases like Google Scholar and Web of Science, writing a program would be hard. However, in Web of Science you can save the list of papers citing A, and the list of papers cited by B. Then I'm sure you can find a way to get their intersection.